# Printing 3D Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, integer

I am trying to print a 3D Array. This is my code:

```
    public static void print(int [][][] array)
{
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++ )
    {
        for (int x=0; x<array[i].length;x++)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("row "+ x);
            for (int j=0; j<array[i][x].length;j++)
            {
                    System.out.print (array[i][x][j]+ " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there something am I doing wrong? 
Every time I call

```
 ThreeDRay.print(d3);
```

I get this error:

> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException   at ThreeDRay.print(ThreeDRay.java:13)   at
> >     ThreeDRayRunner.main(ThreeDRayRunner.java:54)

The rest of the code is this:

```
    public static void main( String args[] )
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);

    out.print("How many matrices do you wish to enter? :: ");
    int matCnt = keyboard.nextInt();

    //instantiate a ThreeDRay

    int[][][] d3= new int [matCnt][][];


    for (int x=0; x < d3.length ;++x){
          d3[x] = new int[0][0];

    for(int i = 0; i < matCnt; i++)
    {
        out.print("What is the size of matrix " + i + " : ");
        int size = keyboard.nextInt();

        int[][] mat = new int[size][size];
        out.println();


        for(int r=0; r<mat.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c=0; c<mat[r].length; c++)
            {
                out.print("Enter a value for spot " + r + " - " + c + " :: ");
               mat[r][c]=keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        }



    if (i==0 && i<matCnt)
    {
    for (int l=0; l<=matCnt; l++){
          out.println("\nThreeDRay before setting mat at spot "+l);



    }
    }


       ThreeDRay.print(d3);


       d3[i] = mat;


        out.println("\nThreeDRay after setting mat at spot "+i);

           ThreeDRay.print(d3);
```

I have to show how I filled the matrices

> > ```
> > //user inputs values for first matrix
> > ```
> >
> > Before adding:
> >
> > Array [0] =
> >
> > Array [1] =
> >
> > Array [2] =
> >
> > //add user inputs
> >
> > After adding:
> >
> > Array [0] = row 0 = [...]
> >
> > ```
> >         row 1 = [...] 
> >
> >        ... depending on user given size of the first matrix Array[1] = Array[2] =
> > ```
> >
> > //ask for inputs for second matrix
> >
> > Before Adding
> >
> > Array [0] = row 0 = [...]
> >
> > ```
> >         row 1 = [...] 
> >
> >        ... depending on user given size of the first matrix Array[1] = Array[2] =
> > ```
> >
> > After adding
> >
> > Array [0] = row 0 = [...]
> >
> > ```
> >       row 1 = [...] 
> >
> >       ... depending on user given size of the first matrix
> > ```
>
> Array[1] = row 0 = [...]
>
> > ```
> >       row 1 = [...] 
> >
> >       ... depending on user given size of the first matrix
> > ```
>
> Array[2] =

Comment: your `d3` array has zero elements !

Comment: Please show the stacktrace. I'm not seeing why you get a NullPointerException. Maybe an index out of bounds

Comment: I just added to my question the desired output, I am trying to demonstrate that the matrix didn't have any values. Then, show that I added the user giving values and that the other two are still empty @ThisaruGuruge

Comment: okay, I just added the error and my desired output to the question @cricket_007

Comment: Have you tried to set some breakpoints in your IDE and inspect the variables to see what's null?

Comment: It is probably in one of your 3 loops: `for (int j=0; j<array[i][x].length;j++)` you are probably trying to read property `length` of a `null` object...

Comment: How do I initialize them? my code has the following line:  int[][][] d3= new int [matCnt][][];  . Doesnt that work? @brso05

Comment: I understand, but I do not know how to initialize it. Could please show me how?@brso05

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yourArray));`

Comment: Proper code formatting and compilable code would have helped …

Comment: @Whatzs, I think that needs to be `Arrays.deepToString()`, otherwise an excellent idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the curly brace in this for loop:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < d3.length; ++x) {
        d3[x] = new int[0][0];
    }
```

Without the closing brace, your program continues into the next for loop after having initialized only one element of `d3` while remaining elements are still null, which gives a `NullPointerException` when you try to print the entire `d3` underway.